# How to sort MySql query by the number of matches in like in Yii framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Suppose I have a table with a column product name. There are various product. I'm trying to find out with some keywords from the table that has matches the product name with the keywords.
For example I have an array $keyword, which have elements like {nokia, lumia, 510}. Now in my database I have a table which has a number of nokia lumia product. While I'm passing this query to search from the data base, it takes all the nokia lumia products in dataProvider. What I'm doing is basically, taking each keyword and put a like %keyword% search on it. Some thing like this.

```
foreach($keywords as $k)
                $array[] = "product_name LIKE '%$k%'";

            $criteria->condition = implode(" OR ", $array);
```

It gives all the result that contains any of the keywords in the product_name, that's good. But I want to short the query according the number of matches in keywords. Like, if I have a product_name "Nokia Lumia 510", then it matches the bosth three cases, then it should be at the 1st position, after rest of the "Nokia Lumia" product, cause they are matching 2 keywords. How to make it on yii.

Answer (score 0):

use order by clause with case conditions

Comment: By what I should order it? I need to order by the number of matches, how can I find that out?